# Pythonic way to convert paragraph to sentence with associated entities

Tags: python

Data is coming from a dataset used to train a ner and it looks like this :

```
'This is my text. It has multiple sentence. It is great'

[{'text': 'is', 'start': 5, 'end': 7, 'type': 'ENTITY'}, {'text' :'has', 'start':20, 'end':23, type:'ENTITY}, {'text': 'is', 'start': 46, 'end': 48, 'type': 'ENTITY'},
```

It's composed of a text with its associated entities. Entities got a `start` and `end` values that determine the position of the first and last character of the word/sequence of word from the beginning of the text.

My goal is to split the text into sentence with the associated entities, this mean to check whether the entity is within the sentence. It also mean to get the correct `start` and `end` position (from start of sentence and not of text).

Here is for example, the desired output for the second sentence of the paragraph. It contains every entities of the sentence with updated `start` and `end` values :

```
 ('This is my text.',
  [{'text': 'is',
    'start': 5,
    'end': 7,
    'type': 'ENTITY'}]),
 ('It has multiple sentence.',
  [{'text': 'has',
    'start': 3,
    'end': 6,
    'type': 'ENTITY'}]),
 ('It is great',
  [{'text': 'is',
    'start': 3,
    'end': 5,
    'type': 'ENTITY'}]),
```

I managed to do it with horrible multiples loops and if, it's quite disguting. If anyone could tell me what's the most pythonic/efficient way to do so ?

If you're curious to see, here's how I did it with loops :

```
def split_sentences(st):
    st = st.strip() + '. '
    sentences = re.split(r'[.?!][.?!\s]+', st)
    return sentences[:-1]


sentences = split_sentences(text)
start_sentence = 0
final_res = []
for text in sentences:
    sentence_ent = []
    for ent in full_line['entities']:
        if(ent['start']-start_sentence < len(text) and ent['start'] - start_sentence >0):
            if(ent['type'] in labels):
                ent['start'] -= start_sentence
                ent['end'] -= start_sentence
                sentence_ent.append(ent)
    if(len(sentence_ent)>0):
        final_res.append((text, sentence_ent))
    start_sentence += len(text)+2
```

Thanks

Comment: by sentence you mean to split by `.` ?

Comment: I edited the code I provided with the split_sentence function I use. This function works great for my case and my problem relies more in doing the entity matching in a pythonic way

Comment: What is your desired output? just correct start and end of each entity? And what if same entity exists in more than 1 sentence?

Comment: My output would be the same as the input but splitted for every sentences. And for each sentence the associated entities with the updated values for start and stop. Give me a minute and I'll edit my question with and example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have used `set` for this

```py
import re

sentence = 'Epidemiology of clinical feline herpesvirus infection in zoo-housed cheetahs (Acinonyx jubatus) OBJECTIVE: To determine the incidence of and risk factors for clinical feline herpesvirus (FHV) infection in zoo-housed cheetahs and determine whether dam infection was associated with offspring infection. DESIGN: Retrospective cohort study. ANIMALS: 144 cheetah cubs born in 6 zoos from 1988 through 2007.'
entities = [{'text': 'feline', 'start': 25, 'end': 31, 'type': 'EUKARYOTE'}, {'text': 'herpesvirus', 'start': 32, 'end': 43, 'type': 'VIRUS'}, {'text': 'zoo', 'start': 57, 'end': 60, 'type': 'ORGANISM'}, {'text': 'cheetahs', 'start': 68, 'end': 76, 'type': 'EUKARYOTE'}, {'text': 'feline', 'start': 167, 'end': 173, 'type': 'EUKARYOTE'}, {'text': 'herpesvirus', 'start': 174, 'end': 185, 'type': 'VIRUS'}, {'text': 'infection', 'start': 192, 'end': 201, 'type': 'DISEASE_OR_SYNDROME'}, {'text': 'zoo', 'start': 205, 'end': 208, 'type': 'ORGANISM'}, {'text': 'cheetahs', 'start': 216, 'end': 224, 'type': 'EUKARYOTE'}, {'text': 'dam infection', 'start': 247, 'end': 260, 'type': 'DISEASE_OR_SYNDROME'}, {'text': 'infection', 'start': 291, 'end': 300, 'type': 'DISEASE_OR_SYNDROME'}, {'text': 'Retrospective cohort study', 'start': 310, 'end': 336, 'type': 'GENE_OR_GENOME'}, {'text': 'ANIMALS', 'start': 338, 'end': 345, 'type': 'CHEMICAL'}, {'text': '144', 'start': 347, 'end': 350, 'type': 'CARDINAL'}, {'text': 'cheetah', 'start': 351, 'end': 358, 'type': 'CHEMICAL'}, {'text': 'cubs', 'start': 359, 'end': 363, 'type': 'ORGANISM'}, {'text': '1988 through', 'start': 384, 'end': 396, 'type': 'DATE'}, {'text': '2007', 'start': 397, 'end': 401, 'type': 'DATE'}]

def split_sentences(st):
    st = st.strip() + '. '
    sentences = re.split(r'[.?!][.?!\s]+', st)
    return sentences[:-1]

splitted_sentence = split_sentences(sentence)
modified_entity = {}
for i in entities:
    modified_entity[i['text'].lower()] = i
    
output = []

for each_sentence in splitted_sentence:
    temp_entity = []
    words = set((i.lower() for i in re.findall(r'\w+', each_sentence)))
    match = words.intersection(modified_entity.keys())

    for each_match in match:
        #start = each_sentence.lower().find(each_match)
        start_end = [i.span() for i in re.finditer(each_match, each_sentence.lower())]
        for start, end in start_end:
            modified_entity[each_match].update({
                'start': start,
                'end': end
            })
            temp_entity.append(modified_entity[each_match].copy())
        
    output.append([each_sentence, temp_entity])
    
print(output)
```

```
[['Epidemiology of clinical feline herpesvirus infection in zoo-housed cheetahs (Acinonyx jubatus) OBJECTIVE: To determine the incidence of and risk factors for clinical feline herpesvirus (FHV) infection in zoo-housed cheetahs and determine whether dam infection was associated with offspring infection',
  [{'text': 'infection',
    'start': 44,
    'end': 53,
    'type': 'DISEASE_OR_SYNDROME'},
   {'text': 'infection',
    'start': 192,
    'end': 201,
    'type': 'DISEASE_OR_SYNDROME'},
   {'text': 'infection',
    'start': 251,
    'end': 260,
    'type': 'DISEASE_OR_SYNDROME'},
   {'text': 'infection',
    'start': 291,
    'end': 300,
    'type': 'DISEASE_OR_SYNDROME'},
   {'text': 'cheetahs', 'start': 68, 'end': 76, 'type': 'EUKARYOTE'},
   {'text': 'cheetahs', 'start': 216, 'end': 224, 'type': 'EUKARYOTE'},
   {'text': 'feline', 'start': 25, 'end': 31, 'type': 'EUKARYOTE'},
   {'text': 'feline', 'start': 167, 'end': 173, 'type': 'EUKARYOTE'},
   {'text': 'zoo', 'start': 57, 'end': 60, 'type': 'ORGANISM'},
   {'text': 'zoo', 'start': 205, 'end': 208, 'type': 'ORGANISM'},
   {'text': 'herpesvirus', 'start': 32, 'end': 43, 'type': 'VIRUS'},
   {'text': 'herpesvirus', 'start': 174, 'end': 185, 'type': 'VIRUS'}]],
 ['DESIGN: Retrospective cohort study', []],
 ['ANIMALS: 144 cheetah cubs born in 6 zoos from 1988 through 2007',
  [{'text': '144', 'start': 9, 'end': 12, 'type': 'CARDINAL'},
   {'text': 'cheetah', 'start': 13, 'end': 20, 'type': 'CHEMICAL'},
   {'text': '2007', 'start': 59, 'end': 63, 'type': 'DATE'},
   {'text': 'cubs', 'start': 21, 'end': 25, 'type': 'ORGANISM'},
   {'text': 'ANIMALS', 'start': 0, 'end': 7, 'type': 'CHEMICAL'}]]]
```

Comment: In case of duplicated words, for example a sentence with twice the same word-entity ('I love cheetahs, cheetahs are cool'). Isn't set() going to be a problem ?

Comment: Set won't be an issue though, the start and end will be the first occurrence of the word in that sentence. You can give it a try with multiple test cases if it suites ur need.

Comment: That's what I meant by problem haha, I'd like to keep all of them and not only the first occurence. Thank you very much for the answer by the way

Comment: that's not an issue of set though, `str.find()` returns the first occurrence. In this scenario you can use regex.

Comment: I feel like there is an easier way but to use regex there as we already have all the informations about the position of the strings and all we have to do is to substract the previous sentence lengths to get it. Don't you think ?

Comment: @JulesCivel I have updated it to check for all occurrences